# Calculating the days til Friday using .getDay()

Tags: javascript, math, logic

finally I had a good reason to jump into stackoverflow, since this question wouldn't let me sleep last night:

Using `new Date().getDay()` I wanna count the days til Friday.

The code is working from Sunday to Friday, but return -1 for Saturdays. I wonder if it's possible using Modulo to solve this mathematically, without an if statement.

So instead of returning -1 on Saturdays, I would love to get 6.

```
let today = new Date().getDay();
let daysToFriday = 5 - today;

console.log(daysToFriday);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let today = new Date().getDay();
let daysToFriday = (12 - today)%7;

console.log(daysToFriday);
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you found my answer is correct, please accept it xD. Happy coding!